# Refinement jquery files for mouseover change content

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover

I want to change content when a user does a mouse-over over a link!
I've searched a lot about this subject. Finally I've found the best solution for myself.

The code includes two `.js` files:

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
      event: "mouseover"
    });
  });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="tabs">
          <nav>
              <ul>
                  <li><a href="#tabs-1">first</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#tabs-2">second</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tabs-3">last</a></li>
              </ul>
          </nav>

<div id="tabs-1">   
<h2>title</h2>  
<p> something </p>
</div>

<div id="tabs-2">   
<h2>title2</h2> 
<p> something2 </p>
</div>

<div id="tabs-3">   
<h2>title3</h2> 
<p> something3 </p>
</div>

</div>
```

My problem is that the two `.js` files are large (730kb total).
Is there anyone that can refine the jQuery files with necessary part, which lets me run this code without any problem?

Thanks!

Comment: use the .min.js files to include for production (small => unreadabe). use the .js files for development (large => readable)

Comment: could you link that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right you just want smaller js files?
If so, jqueryui has a [download builder](http://jqueryui.com/download/) where you can select the parts you want. The downloaded zip includes jquery-ui.min.js which you can then use. It's very small.

And you can use the [minified version of jquery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js) which is only 83KB

Comment: Im bad in js files! for this action ( mouse-over changing div) how i must create right js file with download buidler

Comment: For the code you posted, Toggle All at the top so nothing is selected. Then go down to Widgets and select Tabs (which will automatically add the needed files it depends on) and then below that the Effects Core. Then pick a theme (or no theme if you want to style yourself) and download. From the zip take the jquery-ui.min.js and put it with your other files and then link that on your page.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to include this:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

These files are the minified versions of what you have posted.

Comment: My bad. The second line contains a `jquery-migrate` file. This should be your `jquery-ui.min` file.

Comment: still not working again! i think i do something wrong! i will work on it! thanks